# Ransack use custom fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

In my app I have the model `invoice` which has the attribute `invoice_date`.
In my Ransack search form I want to have a `month` and `year` selectbox and based on these values I want to return the invoices with an invoice date within this period.

But `month` and `year` are not model attributes, so I can't use a `f.select :month_eq` and `f.select :year_eq`. How can I do this?

I looked into `ransackers` and created this in my `invoice` model:

```
ransacker :month do
  year = 2015
  where("invoice_date >= ? and invoice_date <= ?", Date.new(year,month,1), Date.new(year,month).end_of_month)
end
```

How can I use the `month_eq` in this ransacker? And how do I return a collection of invoices?

Answer (score 0):

As i have understood your question, you want a set of results which matches the given month. So in your ransacker, use the following

```
ransacker :month do
  where("extract(month from created_at) =? AND extract(year from created_at) =? ",Date.today.month, 2015)
end
```

Comment: As I understand your answer, it uses the month of today. But it needs to use the month as selected in the search form

Comment: Ya instead of passing Date.today.month you pass the month selected from search form

Comment: But how does that look like? Just `month` or `params[:month]` or `params[:q][:month]`?

Comment: Ya just check from back-end how its coming params[:month] or params[:q][:month]. Mainly depends how you are sending it from the form